# Display payment details and stored into database in ccavenue

Tags: php, mysql, ccavenue

I am working on a CCAvenue payment gateway integration using php. If a user successfully submits the payment, it will be redirected to the payment success page. But after submitting the payment, I need to store the user billing details into my database. How to do it?

Comment: Don't you get billing detail in ccavenue success response?

Comment: CCAcenue Just return order_id and encrypted response. You just need to decrypt it...

Comment: @GyandeepSharma i'll get encrypt data and order id from ccavenue response.how i'll do decrypt that data..

Comment: @AjayKorat ya i'll get success response next wat will i do? for insert data into  databse

Comment: AES Decryption....Search it on google